# How to compute the all combinations of k set bits in parallel?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, combinations, combinatorics

I want to efficiently compute all combinations of an n-bit number (in my case, n=36) with exactly k bits set.

I am thinking something like Gosper's Hack, but parallelizable.

For example, it would be perfect if I could just pass in an index to Gosper's Hack, and it would compute the i'th combination.

```c
unsigned long long permute(unsigned long long val, unsigned long long i)
{
    int ffs = __builtin_ffsll(val);
    val |= (val - 1);

    // Do something here with `i` to produce the i'th combination, rather than the next one.

    return (val + 1) | (((~val & -(~val)) - 1) >> ffs);
}
```

Also, in my case, the combinations don't necessarily need to be in lexicographical order. Any ordering will do as long as all combinations are generated.

Comment: Parallelizable in general might be easier than indexable. Indexable would be more ubiquitous though.

Comment: since Gosper's hack iterates from lowest to highest you can divide your space into ranges and then the question is about finding the lowest n-bit-set value above the range start - if the start of range has l bits set, you need to set (k - l) lowest bits to one and start from there. If `k < l` then you have a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it as below, following [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system#Example):

```
long to_combination(int k, int N) {
  if (N == 0) {
    return (1L<<k)-1;
  }
  int n;
  for (n=k; C(n,k)<=N; n++)
    ;
  n--;
  return (1L<<n) | to_combination(k-1, N - C(n,k));
}
```

Calling `to_combination(5, 72)` returns 331 (`101001011` in binary, representing `{8, 6, 3, 1, 0}`), as in the example.